# How to extract the key words containing row from an excel file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, python, perl

I need to extract the key-words containing row from an excel file (.xls) as per the order specified in the given key-word file. For example
I have an excel file namely genome.xls as given below,

```
NC_0208.1   18918   94692   amyl4_A0A0H         1   54  194
NC_0208.1   18839   86123   prot4_A0A0          1   79  137
NC_0208.4   29761   74985   lip10_H8FLU5        2   393 48
NC_0208.2   29687   67745   lysin6_A0A0Q5       5   38  49
```

And I have a key word file namely id.txt as given below,

```
prot
lip
cellulase
lysin
amyl
```

The expected output is

```
NC_0208.1   18839   86123   prot4_A0A0          1   79  137
NC_0208.4   29761   74985   lip10_H8FLU5        2   393 48

NC_0208.2   29687   67745   lysin6_A0A0Q5       5   38  49 
NC_0208.1   18918   94692   amyl4_A0A0H         1   54  194
```

In addition to this, if the key-words are not there in genome file, it should leave the entire row as empty in the output file. 
Inorder to do this, I used grep command as follows,

```
grep 'prot\|lip\|cellulase\|lysin\|amyl' genome.xls > result.xls
```

Above mentioned command is extracting the key word containing entire row, but the order has been changed. Moreover, it is not leaving an empty row for the missing key words. 
Therefore, kindly help me to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirements demand a loop over the keywords. I would recommend the following shell-script (although you can absorb in into a one-liner if you want to):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read keyword
do
    # Apply grep, but store result in variable
    MATCH="$(grep $keyword genome.xls)"

    # If grep result is an empty string, output an empty line,
    # otherwise the grep result as-is.
    if [[ -z "$MATCH" ]]
    then
        echo
    else
        echo "$MATCH"
    fi
done < id.txt
```

By looping about the content of `id.txt` you can assure the ordering of the output.

Call the script with

```
user@host$ ./extract_lines.sh > result.xml
```

In order to make the script more flexible, we can make the file to be processed a command-line argument, or even a list of command-line arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" == "0" ]]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <filename(s)>"
    exit 1
fi


for file in "$@"
do
    outfile=${file/.xls/_result.xls}
    :>$outfile

    echo "Process $file, write results to $outfile"


    while read keyword
    do
    # Apply grep, but store result in variable
    MATCH="$(grep $keyword $file)"

    # If grep result is an empty string, output an empty line,
    # otherwise the grep result as-is.
    if [[ -z "$MATCH" ]]
    then
            echo "" >> $outfile
    else
            echo "$MATCH" >> $outfile
    fi
    done < id.txt
done
```

This will loop over all files specified as command-line arguments (and be it `*.xls`) and write the results to `<input_filename>_result.xls`.

**Note** however that this syntax is somewhat rudimentary in that you should not mix filename specifications with "globs" (i.e. wildcards like `*`) and regular filenames in your argument list.

Comment: @user357294 updated the answer. I still assume that `id.txt` can be left hard-coded in the implementation.

Comment: Thank you @AdminBee

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
while read a ; do grep "$a" genome.xls || printf "\n" ; done < id.txt 

NC_0208.1   18839   86123   prot4_A0A0          1   79  137
NC_0208.4   29761   74985   lip10_H8FLU5        2   393 48

NC_0208.2   29687   67745   lysin6_A0A0Q5       5   38  49 
NC_0208.1   18918   94692   amyl4_A0A0H         1   54  194
```

Comment: Thank you msp9011, AdminBee.  I have multiple excel files to do the same. Therefore, I tried to save all excel files in `for file in *.xls` and used `"$file"` instead of `genome.xls` and end up with error. I also tried to call all the file as `*.xls` instead of `genome.xls`, but the results have been printed in the same file or single file. In order to store each excel file grep result separately, I have tried this syntax `"$file" | uniq > "new_${file}"` , but this also not working. Sorry, I have not mentioned this condition in my question. could you please suggest something to do the same.